# How to recite long surah in namaz (prayer)

Tags: salat, practical-islam, fiqh, quran-recitation

I want to learn surah Rahman and recite it while I pray. but I do not know how to break down the surah and pray.please help and advise what is the procedure to read long surah in prayer
Jazakallah

Answer (score 1):

Good to know that you are planning to Hifz Surah Rehman and recite in namaz.
One can recite as many ayats in a rakah as desired or memorized. Better to recite at least 3 short ayats in a rakah, or 1 long ayat (eg ayatul Kursi). You can recite any number of ayats. Or you can recite 1 ruku in each rakat.
Hope this clarifies.